# Am trying to read this csv file but I keep getting a range out of index, any ideas on how to avoid it?

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, truthtable

Am trying to read this csv file that I will later choose the distinct elements in it and create a truth table if each element exists in a row I put 1 If not 0
The line/row length keeps isn't constant and that's what am having trouble with

```
chicken,other vegetables,packaged fruit/vegetables,condensed milk,frozen vegetables,fruit/vegetable juice
vinegar,oil
rolls/buns,soda,specialty bar
whole milk
pork,root vegetables,whole milk,whipped/sour cream
rolls/buns,newspapers
grapes,other vegetables,zwieback,Instant food products,dishes
frankfurter,citrus fruit,whipped/sour cream,cream cheese ,rolls/buns,baking powder,seasonal products,napkins
finished products,root vegetables,packaged fruit/vegetables,yogurt,specialty cheese,frozen vegetables,ice cream,soda,bottled beer
onions,other vegetables,flour
tropical fruit,whole milk,rolls/buns
```

Am using this following code

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string filepath = @"C:\Downloads\groceriess.csv";
    DataTable res = ConvertCSVtoDataTable(filepath);

    DataTable ConvertCSVtoDataTable(string strFilePath)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strFilePath);
        string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (string header in headers)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(header);
        }
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string[] rows = Regex.Split(sr.ReadLine(), ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
            { //i did try i<rows.Length and also i < headers.Length && i <rows.Length
              dr[i] = rows[i]; //this is the line that is causing the error
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
     }
}
```

Comment: `headers` is six elements taken from the first line, but in the 8th line (starts with frankfurter) there are eight elements

Comment: Try `i < dt.Columns.Count && i < rows.Length`. These are the two indexed objects involved and the index must not exceed their range.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes It crashes without showing anything

Comment: Run this code and Debug mode and [debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the code in the question is meant to read a CSV file with a header row and a fixed number of columns. However, that is not what your data is.

The best you can do is to store the data in a `List<List<string>>`, something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Groceries
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static List<List<string>> LoadGroceryList(string filename)
        {
            var groceryList = new List<List<string>>();

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var items = Regex.Split(line, ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
                    if (items.Length > 0) { groceryList.Add(items.ToList()); }
                }
            }

            return groceryList;

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filepath = @"C:\temp\Groceries.csv";
            var groceries = LoadGroceryList(filepath);

            var uniqueItems = groceries.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().OrderBy(y => y);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", uniqueItems));

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

For the data in the question, that outputs:

```
baking powder
bottled beer
chicken
citrus fruit
condensed milk
cream cheese
dishes
finished products
flour
frankfurter
frozen vegetables
fruit/vegetable juice
grapes
ice cream
Instant food products
napkins
newspapers
oil
onions
other vegetables
packaged fruit/vegetables
pork
rolls/buns
root vegetables
seasonal products
soda
specialty bar
specialty cheese
tropical fruit
vinegar
whipped/sour cream
whole milk
yogurt
zwieback
```

Comment: Thank you It works

Answer (score 0):

Your code means that the number of items in a row must be *exactly* equal to `header.length`. But in your CSV file, each row has a different length from the others.

You must check the number of items in each row separately from header length.

Comment: Csv files have a large number of lines, I cannot go and count each row how many elements it has. Am looking for an optimal automatic solution not a manual one but thank you for pointing out the problem.